# IF statement which only calculates to 2 decimal places

Tags: excel, if-statement

My IF statement:

```
=IF(AL23*0.2=AM23,"a","r")
```

Calculates VAT to 3 decimal places so when its checking with AM23 it is returning a false as I only have VAT to 2 decimal places.

How can I make the IF statement only calculate the AL23*0.2 to 2.dps?

Answer (score 3):

You can round it like this:

```
=IF(ROUND(AL23*0.2,2)=AM23,"a","r")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROUND`, which rounds the first argument to the number of decimal places specified by the second argument

```
=IF(ROUND(AL23 * 0.2, 2) = AM23, "a", "r")
```

Consider `ROUNDDOWN` or `ROUNDUP` for other rounding behaviour: `ROUND` will round half-way cases and higher upwards.

(Also, consider not hardcoding the VAT rate in a formula in case it changes in the future.)

Answer (score 1):

The round function should work

```
round(AL23*0.2,2)
```

so the full statement should be:

```
=IF(round(AL23*0.2,2)=AM23,"a","r")
```